# System Performance with VS 2017

Tags: .net, xamarin, cpu-architecture

I am looking to build a new development PC. Day to day tasks includes building large .NET solutions with > 7 projects in VS 2017. I work with Xamarin, my build times are rather long, > 5 mins.

I currently run an Intel CPU but I am reading more about AMD being more suited to workstations.

So, what considerations should I give to CPU, Ram & SSD

Comment: Compiling is a highly parallel task that's mostly CPU-bound unless your RAM is very small.  A faster / many-core CPU will make a big difference for building large projects with many source files, e.g. maybe a factor of 8 from a dual-core laptop to a 16-core AMD ThreadRipper.  Intel CPUs are still faster on a per-core basis, but you can get more throughput for a good price with AMD currently, I think.  Compiler benchmarks should be easy to find.  If not for MSVC, then for gcc, which might be similar.

Comment: e.g. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Core-i9-Threadripper-Linux-4.15 has benchmarks for building Apache, gcc, and the Linux kernel on a ThreadRipper 1950X (16c/32t) vs. a Core i9 7980XE (Skylake-AVX512: 18c/36t)